# How to implement a zooming function with header and footer support in PagesTextEdit forked by dimkanovikov on github?

Tags: python, qt, pagination, pyqt5, word-processor

I am now currently working on a MS Word clone with Python 3 and want some effect with pagination support. I saw some implementations in https://forum.qt.io/topic/847/paginating-a-qtextedit/2, and I found the repository of dimkanovikov (https://github.com/dimkanovikov/PagesTextEdit). After that, I found the implementation of the translation for this code (https://github.com/BrightSoftwareFoundation/PagesTextEdit), but it is buggy, so I made a few changes to it. Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

###### QPageMetrics.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class PageMetrics:

    def __init__(self):

        self.m_mmPageSize = QSizeF()
        self.m_mmPageMargins = QMarginsF()
        self.m_pxPageSize = QSizeF()
        self.m_pxPageMargins = QMarginsF()
        self.m_zoomRange = 0.0

    def mmToInches(self, mm):
        return mm * 0.039370147

    def mmToPx(self, _mm, _x=True):
        return self.mmToInches(_mm) * \
               (qApp.desktop().logicalDpiX() if _x else
                qApp.desktop().logicalDpiY())

    def pageMetrics(self, _pageFormat=QPageSize.PageSizeId, _mmPageMargins=QMarginsF()):
        self.update(_pageFormat, _mmPageMargins)

    def setPxPageSize(self, _width, _height):
        self.m_mmPageSize = QSizeF(_width, _height)
        self.m_pxPageSize = QSizeF(self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageSize.width(), True),
                                   self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageSize.height(), False))

    def update(self, _pageFormat, _mmPageMargins=QMarginsF()):
        self.m_pageFormat = _pageFormat

        self.m_mmPageSize = QPageSize(self.m_pageFormat).rect(QPageSize.Unit.Millimeter).size()
        self.m_mmPageMargins = _mmPageMargins

        x = True
        y = False

        self.m_pxPageSize = QSizeF(self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageSize.width(), x),
                                   self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageSize.height(), y))

        self.m_pxPageMargins = QMarginsF(self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageMargins.left(), x),
                                         self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageMargins.top(), y),
                                         self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageMargins.right(), x),
                                         self.mmToPx(self.m_mmPageMargins.bottom(), y))

    def pageFormat(self):
        return self.m_pageFormat

    def mmPageSize(self):
        return self.m_mmPageSize

    def mmPageMargins(self):
        return self.m_mmPageMargins

    def pxPageSize(self):
        return QSizeF(self.m_pxPageSize.width(),
                      self.m_pxPageSize.height())

    def pxPageMargins(self):
        return QMarginsF(self.m_pxPageMargins.left(),
                         self.m_pxPageMargins.top(),
                         self.m_pxPageMargins.right(),
                         self.m_pxPageMargins.bottom())

    def zoomIn(self, _zoomRange=float()):
        self.m_zoomRange = _zoomRange
```

###### PagesTextEdit.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import QPageMetrics as pe

import sys


class PagesTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.m_document = QTextDocument()
        self.m_usePageMode = True
        self.m_addBottomSpace = True
        self.m_showPageNumbers = True
        self.m_pageNumbersAlignment = Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignRight
        self.m_pageMetrics = pe.PageMetrics()
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.aboutDocumentChanged()
        self.textChanged.connect(self.aboutDocumentChanged)
        self.verticalScrollBar().rangeChanged.connect(self.aboutVerticalScrollRangeChanged)

    def setPageFormat(self, _pageFormat):
        self.m_pageMetrics.update(_pageFormat)
        self.repaint()

    def setPageMargins(self, _margins):
        self.m_pageMetrics.update(self.m_pageMetrics.pageFormat(), _margins)
        self.repaint()

    def paintEvent(self, _event):
        self.updateVerticalScrollRange()
        self.paintPageView()
        self.paintPageNumbers()
        super().paintEvent(_event)

    def resizeEvent(self, _event):
        self.updateViewportMargins()
        super().resizeEvent(_event)

    def updateViewportMargins(self):
        self.viewportMargins = QMargins()
        if self.m_usePageMode:
            self.pageWidth = int(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().width())
            self.pageHeight = int(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().height())

            self.DEFAULT_TOP_MARGIN = int(20)
            self.DEFAULT_BOTTOM_MARGIN = int(20)

            self.leftMargin = int(0)
            self.rightMargin = int(0)

            if self.width() > self.pageWidth:
                self.BORDERS_WIDTH = int(4)
                self.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_WIDTH = int(self.verticalScrollBar().width()
                                                    if self.verticalScrollBar().isVisible()
                                                    else 0)
                self.leftMargin = self.rightMargin = int((self.width() - self.pageWidth -
                                                      self.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_WIDTH - self.BORDERS_WIDTH) / 2)
                self.topMargin = int(self.DEFAULT_TOP_MARGIN)
                self.bottomMargin = int(self.DEFAULT_BOTTOM_MARGIN)
                self.documentHeight = int(self.pageHeight * self.document().pageCount())

                if (self.height() - self.documentHeight) > (self.DEFAULT_TOP_MARGIN + self.DEFAULT_BOTTOM_MARGIN):
                    self.BORDERS_HEIGHT = int(2)
                    self.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_HEIGHT = int(self.horizontalScrollBar().height()
                                                           if self.horizontalScrollBar().isVisible()
                                                           else 0)
                    self.bottomMargin = int(self.height() - self.documentHeight -
                                            self.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_HEIGHT - self.DEFAULT_TOP_MARGIN -
                                            self.BORDERS_HEIGHT)

                self.viewportMargins = QMargins(self.leftMargin, self.topMargin, self.rightMargin, self.bottomMargin)

        self.setViewportMargins(self.viewportMargins)
        self.aboutUpdateDocumentGeometry()

    def updateVerticalScrollRange(self):
        if self.m_usePageMode:
            self.pageHeight = int(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().height())
            self.documentHeight = int(self.pageHeight * self.document().pageCount())
            self.maximumValue = int(self.documentHeight - self.viewport().height())

            if self.verticalScrollBar().maximum() != self.maximumValue:
                self.verticalScrollBar().setMaximum(self.maximumValue)
        else:
            self.SCROLL_DELTA = int(800)
            self.maximumValue = int(self.document().size().height() - self.viewport().size().height() +
                                    (self.SCROLL_DELTA if self.m_addBottomSpace else 0))

            if self.verticalScrollBar().maximum() != self.maximumValue:
                self.verticalScrollBar().setMaximum(self.maximumValue)

    def paintPageView(self):
        if self.m_usePageMode:
            self.pageWidth = float(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().width())
            self.pageHeight = float(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().height())

            self.p = QPainter(self.viewport())
            self.spacePen = QPen(self.palette().window(), 9)
            self.borderPen = QPen(self.palette().dark(), 1)

            self.curHeight = float(self.pageHeight - (self.verticalScrollBar().value() %
                                                      int(self.pageHeight)))

            self.canDrawNextPageLine = self.verticalScrollBar().value() != \
                self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()

            self.xValueF = self.pageWidth + (1 if (self.width() % 2 == 0) else 0)
            self.xValue = int(self.xValueF)
            self.horizontalDelta = int(self.horizontalScrollBar().value())

            if (self.curHeight - self.pageHeight) >= 0:
                self.p.setPen(self.borderPen)
                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(0), self.curHeight - self.pageHeight,
                                       self.xValueF, self.curHeight - self.pageHeight))

            while self.curHeight <= self.height():
                self.p.setPen(self.spacePen)
                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(0), float(self.curHeight - 4),
                                       float(self.width()), float(self.curHeight - 4)))
                self.p.setPen(self.borderPen)
                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(0), float(self.curHeight - 0),
                                       self.xValueF, self.curHeight))
                if self.canDrawNextPageLine:
                    self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(0),
                                           float(self.curHeight - 8),
                                           float(self.pageWidth),
                                           float(self.curHeight - 8)))

                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(0 - self.horizontalDelta), float(self.curHeight - self.pageHeight),
                                       float(0 - self.horizontalDelta), float(self.curHeight - 8)))
                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(self.xValueF - self.horizontalDelta),
                                       float(self.curHeight - self.pageHeight),
                                       float(self.xValueF - self.horizontalDelta),
                                       float(self.curHeight - 8)))
                self.curHeight += self.pageHeight

            if self.curHeight >= self.height():
                self.p.setPen(self.borderPen)
                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(0 - self.horizontalDelta), float(self.curHeight - self.pageHeight),
                                       float(0 - self.horizontalDelta), float(self.height())))
                self.p.drawLine(QLineF(float(self.xValueF - self.horizontalDelta),
                                       float(self.curHeight - self.pageHeight),
                                       float(self.xValueF - self.horizontalDelta),
                                       float(self.height())))

    def paintPageNumbers(self):
        if (self.m_usePageMode and not self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageMargins().isNull() and
                self.m_showPageNumbers):
            self.pageSize = QSizeF(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize())
            self.pageMargins = QMarginsF(self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageMargins())

            self.p = QPainter(self.viewport())
            self.p.setFont(self.document().defaultFont())
            self.p.setPen(QPen(self.palette().text(), 1))

            self.curHeight = float(self.pageSize.height() - (self.verticalScrollBar().value() %
                                                             int(self.pageSize.height())))
            self.leftMarginPosition = float(self.pageMargins.left() - self.pageMargins.right())
            self.marginWidth = float(self.pageSize.width() - self.pageMargins.left() - self.pageMargins.right())
            self.pageNumber = int(self.verticalScrollBar().value() / self.pageSize.height() + 1)

            if self.curHeight - self.pageMargins.top() >= 0:
                self.topMarginRect = QRectF(float(self.leftMarginPosition),
                                            float(self.curHeight - self.pageSize.height()),
                                            float(self.marginWidth),
                                            float(self.pageMargins.top()))
                self.paintPageNumber(self.p, self.topMarginRect, True, self.pageNumber)

            while self.curHeight < self.height():
                self.bottomMarginRect = QRect(int(self.leftMarginPosition),
                                              int(self.curHeight - self.pageMargins.bottom()),
                                              int(self.marginWidth),
                                              int(self.pageMargins.bottom()))
                self.paintPageNumber(self.p, self.bottomMarginRect, False, self.pageNumber)
                self.pageNumber += 1
                self.topMarginRect = QRect(int(self.leftMarginPosition), int(self.curHeight), int(self.marginWidth),
                                           int(self.pageMargins.top()))
                self.paintPageNumber(self.p, self.topMarginRect, True, self.pageNumber)

                self.curHeight += self.pageSize.height()
            self.p.end()

    def paintPageNumber(self, _painter, _rect, _isHeader, _number):
        if _isHeader:
            if self.m_pageNumbersAlignment == Qt.AlignTop:
                _painter.drawText(_rect, Qt.AlignVCenter | (self.m_pageNumbersAlignment ^ Qt.AlignTop),
                                  str(_number))
        else:
            if self.m_pageNumbersAlignment == Qt.AlignBottom:
                _painter.drawText(_rect, Qt.AlignVCenter | (self.m_pageNumbersAlignment ^ Qt.AlignBottom),
                                  str(_number))

    def aboutVerticalScrollRangeChanged(self, _minimum, _maximum):
        self.updateViewportMargins()
        self.scrollValue = int(self.verticalScrollBar().value())

        if self.scrollValue > _maximum:
            self.updateVerticalScrollRange()

    def aboutDocumentChanged(self):
        if self.m_document != self.document():
            self.m_document = self.document()
            self.document().documentLayout().update.connect(self.aboutUpdateDocumentGeometry)

    def aboutUpdateDocumentGeometry(self):
        self.documentSize = QSizeF(float(self.width() - self.verticalScrollBar().width()), float(-1))

        if self.m_usePageMode:
            self.pageWidth = (self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().width())
            self.pageHeight = (self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageSize().height())
            self.documentSize = QSizeF(self.pageWidth, self.pageHeight)

            if self.width() > self.pageWidth:
                self.viewportMargins = QMargins(
                    int(int(self.width() - self.pageWidth - self.verticalScrollBar().width() - 2) / 2),
                    20,
                    int(int(self.width() - self.pageWidth - self.verticalScrollBar().width() - 2) / 2),
                    20
                )
            else:
                self.viewportMargins = QMargins(0, 20, 0, 20)

        if self.document().pageSize() != self.documentSize:
            self.document().setPageSize(self.documentSize)

        if self.document().documentMargin() != 0:
            self.document().setDocumentMargin(0)

        rootFrameMargin = self.m_pageMetrics.pxPageMargins()
        rootFrameFormat = self.document().rootFrame().frameFormat()

        self.setViewportMargins(self.viewportMargins)

        if ((rootFrameFormat.leftMargin() != rootFrameMargin.left())
            | (rootFrameFormat.topMargin() != rootFrameMargin.top())
            | (rootFrameFormat.rightMargin() != rootFrameMargin.right())
            | (rootFrameFormat.bottomMargin() != rootFrameMargin.bottom())):
            rootFrameFormat.setLeftMargin(rootFrameMargin.left())
            rootFrameFormat.setTopMargin(rootFrameMargin.top())
            rootFrameFormat.setRightMargin(rootFrameMargin.right())
            rootFrameFormat.setBottomMargin(rootFrameMargin.bottom())
            self.document().rootFrame().setFrameFormat(rootFrameFormat)
```

Here are some few questions I want to ask:

1. How to implement a zooming function in the paged text edit like MS Word that zooms the whole page but not only text? I have tried different methods: using `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, delete the `resizeEvent`, try to implement a `QScrollArea` with `setFrameRect`, ... It crashes often, `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) / RESTART: SHELL` or `RecursionError` often appears.
2. How to change the page size? It does not crash, only for `self.setPageSize(QPageSize.PageSizeId.A4)` or `.A5)`. For another size or custom one, it crashes with `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) / RESTART: SHELL`.
3. My page numbering / header and footer cannot be shown for an unknown reason. Can somebody help me to solve this?

Any comments / answers are appreciated!

Comment: With all due respect, StackOverflow is not a help desk. While we might be more attracted by questions that are more challenging than the average ones, it seems like you just want to try to achieve something only by trial and error, while dealing with extremely complex aspects of uncommon implementations, and then ask us how to fix them. For instance, in your 1st question you're referring to QGraphicsProxyWidget (and there's absolutely no QGraphicsView use in your links), "delete the resizeEvent" (which makes no sense) and `setFrameRect()` (which is irrelevant for the layout of the contents).

Comment: What you're asking is (probably) not impossible, but it's very difficult to achieve: it requires profound knowledge/experience of Qt, especially related to the internal frameworks you need to use: the rich-text API (QTextDocument/QTextCursor), the Graphics View framework, and not forgetting about platform issues about font scaling, screen DPI, etc. And all that is too broad for the scope of StackOverflow, which is to answer *specific, detailed questions*, not "how to get some features out of my MS Word clone based on someone else's code".

Comment: Fine, I will try it.